# All the skirts are quite full

Tags: meaning

So we walked as far as Kensington High Street, and we looked at the shops. **All the skirts are quite full.** Ambrose Kimberley was frightfully nice. He said he didn’t often meet a girl like me.

It's from the novel "Grey Mask" by Patricia Wentworth (1929).

What is the meaning of 'All the skirts are quite full.' ?

Comment: It is a little ambiguous.  It could be referring to skirts in the shop windows, or it could be referring to the skirts on the women walking along.  If the latter it would presumably imply that the local residents were "high class".  It would be hard to be certain without understanding the context and writer's style in greater detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it refers to the skirts in the window shops.

A [full skirt](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/full+skirt):

> - a long skirt gathered at the waist. TFD

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The fullness of a skirt refers to how much material is gathered into the waist. A full skirt is considered modest dress because there is a lot of material in the gathers, and they are usually quite long because of this, although the length is not explicit in the description.

The opposite of a full skirt is a pencil skirt (for example) that is quite form-fitting.

Comment: Pencil skirt: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pencil-skirt

Answer (score -2):

It means that there weren't any short shirt at the shops.

Comment: Fullness is rather more about width than length.  See the other answers.